# Sorting lists by column

Tags: python, file, sorting, fwrite, enumerate

At the moment I am trying to sort a file with data such as:

```
[Name] [Score]  
[Name] [Score]
```

And this goes on. I am trying to sort it by score. So my method is to get all the data from a file and sort it. However I use the sort function and it puts all the data in this format:

```
[Name] [Score] [Name] [Score]
```

I want it to be:

```
[Name] [Score]  
[Name] [Score]
```

then write that to file instead

```
def fileWrite(fName, fClass):
    fileName = "%s %s" %(fClass, ".txt")
    fileName = fileName.replace(" ", "")
    return(fileName)

def fileSort(fName, fClass):
    fSort = open(fName, "a+")
    contents = []
    i = getFileData(fName)
    for getData in range(i):
        data1 = fSort.readline()
        replaceWith = "%s %s" %(fClass, ";")
        data1 = data1.replace(fClass, replaceWith)
        contents.append(data1)
    contents.sort()
    print contents
    fSort.truncate(0)
    fSort.write(contents)

def getFileData(fName):
    i = 0
    with open(fName) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1
```

Here is some of the data from the file I need to sort:

```
Reece 10
John 4
Alex 7
Alex 8
John 4
Alex 6
Reece 9
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `zip()`. Could you add a small excerpt of your file?

Comment: I am not familiar with that function at all. I am not that good at Python yet.

Comment: That's ok, that's what this forum is for :) If you could add to your question a little bit of the data file you are processing (just a few lines are enough), we could help you solve this issue.

Comment: Please give a piece of the file you use as input (you can edit your post and put it in). We'll help you when we know how to help you :)

Comment: I have added some file data

Comment: @Reece what is `fClass` in your code? It is not defined.

Comment: Also the function `fileSort` is not returning anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can first load your data into pairs like this:

```
pairs = [l.strip().split(' ') for l in open('data.txt', 'r')]
```

Now you can sort them like this:

```
pairs.sort(key = lambda name_score: int(name_score[1]))
```

Finally, you can change them back into a string like this:

```
'\n'.join(name_score[0] + ' ' + name_score[1] for name_score in pairs)
```

You can just `open` a file, and `write` this string into it.

Answer (score 3):

You should give [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) a try.

You won't have pandas installed readily with your python. So first you might have to install it - `pip install pandas` or `easy_install pandas` - for which you will require `python-setuptools`. Install them with `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`.

```
import pandas
# Read your file as a dataframe in Pandas.
# "sep" is your delimiter "header" row index are options
myData = pandas.read_csv("/path/to/file.txt",sep=",",header=0)
# Now sort with your column key 
sortData = myData.sort(['score'])
# Write out your dataframe to csv
sortData.to_csv("/path/to/output.txt",sep=",",index=False,header=True)
```

I haven tried it on this data - in some file `file.txt`

```
name,score
Reece,10
John,4
Alex,7
Alex,8
John,4
Alex,6
Reece,9
```

Output -

```
name,score
John,4
John,4
Alex,6
Alex,7
Alex,8
Reece,9
Reece,10
```

Edit: header index changed to 0 instead of 1

Comment: This is a good and easy to implement answer. The OP is new to Python though, so you could perhaps add a small description line-by-line of what your code does? As comments within the code would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Do as this,

Get File content:

```
with open(yourfile, "r") as f:
    data = [l.split(" ") for l in f]
```

sort it:

```
sortedList = sort(data, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

or using [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
import operator
sortedList = sort(data, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: You don't need to buffer the lines to a list with `readlines()`; `f` is already an iterable.

Comment: @WillVousden, true :)